# Increment a row in SQL Server database after the LAST row within a range

Tags: sql-server, select, range

I have tried looking for an answer for my question but due to lack of proper knowledge in databases, I thought some genius here could help me out.

I'm trying to add rows into a database table starting from the number 800 and onwards in a sequential order. The database currently has records from 1 up until 300.

This record in the table is not automatically incremented, but assigned manually.

I basically want to start another batch of numbers, but rather than incrementing them from where the program left off (i.e. from 300) I would like to start them from 800.

I tried different SQL statements but got nothing concrete to go with. I'm using PHP to enter these rows.

I feel like this shouldn't be so hard but I'm a novice and it kills!

I thought maybe adding one record that starts from 800 and then executing a statement like

```
SELECT LAST FROM A RANGE BETWEEN 800 AND 899
```

would be the way to go.

Any help, advice?

Comment: What database are you working with specifically?

Comment: A combination of the max function and a where clause should get you what you need.  select max(recordnumber) from table where recordnumber => 800 and recordnumber <= 899

Comment: Make sure and pay attention to marc_s 's comment on Jack Edmond's answer. With any of the answers you receive, you'll want to consider the concurrency issues with the solution. To do this 'right', it will be a much more difficult problem than it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the highest numbered record with the `MAX` aggregate function.  The following will find the next highest number that is between 800 and 899.

```
SELECT MAX(my_assigned_number) + 1 as next_number
FROM my_table
WHERE my_assigned_number > 800 AND my_assigned_number < 899;
```

Comment: You do know that this will fail horribly on a busy system, right? When multiple concurrent users are requesting new ID's by using the `MAX(ID)+1` approach, you're **guaranteed** to get duplicates  .....